# Text mining Clustering Analysis in R - Error :Two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, k-means, text-mining

I'm trying to follow a document that has some code on text mining clustering analysis.
I'm fairly new to R and the concept of text mining/clustering so please bear with me if i sound illiterate.

I create a simple matrix called dtm and then run kmeans to produce 3 clusters. The code im having issues is where a function has been defined to get "five most common words of the documents  in the cluster"

```
dtm0.75 = as.matrix(dt0.75)
dim(dtm0.75)

kmeans.result = kmeans(dtm0.75, 3)

perClusterCounts = function(df, clusters, n)
{
  v = sort(colSums(df[clusters == n, ]), 
           decreasing = TRUE)
  d = data.frame(word = names(v), freq = v)
  d[1:5, ]
}
perClusterCounts(dtm0.75, kmeans.result$cluster, 1)
```

Upon running this code i get the following error:

Error in colSums(df[clusters == n, ]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Could someone help me fix this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, it works fine for me. Update your question with a reproducible example and you might get a more useful answer. Perhaps your input data object is empty, what do you get with `dim(dtm0.75)`?

Here it is working fine on the data that comes with the `tm` package:

```
library(tm)
data(crude)

dt0.75 <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)

dtm0.75 = as.matrix(dt0.75)
dim(dtm0.75)

kmeans.result = kmeans(dtm0.75, 3)

perClusterCounts = function(df, clusters, n)
{
  v = sort(colSums(df[clusters == n, ]), 
           decreasing = TRUE)
  d = data.frame(word = names(v), freq = v)
  d[1:5, ]
}
perClusterCounts(dtm0.75, kmeans.result$cluster, 1)

                 word freq
the               the   69
and               and   25
for               for   12
government government   11
oil               oil   10
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. when i ran dim(dt0.75), i got > dim(dtm0.75)
[1] 1000   1. Basically, dtm0.75 is a simple matrix created from dm0.75 which was another matrix/dataset that was created by removing sparse terms at 0.25 level. When i changed that level to 0.75 instead, the entire thing seems to have worked. So it looks like using 0.25 did something to the matrix that was not going to work with the code. I have no clue what it is though

Comment: Sounds like you made your dtm too sparse so you only had one term in it... Has your question been answered here?